# Docker EE Admin UI vs Portainer

Tags: docker

I just heard about the integrated admin UI in Docker EE.
So I wonder what is *special* about that UI because I also can have such a UI in Docker CE with portainer. 
What's the difference between both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @herm said, at the moment, the Docker EE UI (Docker UCP) has more Docker related features than Portainer (support for Docker-compose is not available yet for example). Almost all of the features available in UCP are planned in Portainer and developers are focusing a lot on the user experience to make it really easy to use and deploy.

You'll find that access control is a bit different in Portainer than in UCP (Portainer allows you to restrict access on your Docker environments as well as your Docker resources).

Answer (score 2):

The docker EE Ui has more features than portainer. You can view logs of all containers, there is some performance monitoring and other features. As far as I know portainer does a subset of what the Docker EE universal control plane does.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed while doing trial with **Docker EE** is how diverse and complex is RBAC.

You define Grants based on:

- Subject - node in a tree of Orgs\Teams\Users (which can be automatically synced from LDAP\AD)
- Object - node in a tree of Collections of resources
- Access right - is called a Role (5 built-in + custom) and is a set of Permissions (allowed operations) over almost any entity you can imagine (containers, networks, volumes, images, nodes, configs, secrets, services etc)

See example of Grants:
https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/access-control/access-control-design-ee-advanced/#grant-composition

Add to that big emphasis on:

- TLS - for UCP, DTR and even Client Bundles per user
- High-Availability (extends docker swarm)
- lots of UI operations are possible to do in CLI, and all are possible via API (which transparently extends Docker Engine API) so helps with large-scale automations

Docker EE will better suit big enterprises which require strict access control (Government, Military, Aero-Space). But then you get free Kubernetes with a bunch of commercial support options...

Architecturally Docker EE is made of many "system" containers - I counted 13 for UCP and 9 for DTR, which also imposes serious load on a hardware.
Installation process is long and cumbersome.
See Docker EE architecture: https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/architecture/

Portainer is I believe just 1 container and quite light. And muuuuch cheaper for commercial option. We use free option and it's enough for us! (but we are small ~100 cores estate)